# Unable to retrieve shared preferences data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.icu.util.VersionInfo
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.renderscript.Sampler
import android.text.LoginFilter
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ET1).text
        val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ET2).text

        val username1 = getSharedPreferences("username", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        username1.edit().putString("username", username.toString()).apply()

        val password1 = getSharedPreferences("password", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        password1.edit().putString("password", password.toString()).apply()
        /*val rememberme = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)*/
        val loginbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.LoginButton)
        /*val register = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2)*/

        loginbutton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("username is ",username1.getString("username","").toString())
            Log.i("username is ",password1.getString("password","").toString())
            val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }



    }

}
```

Problem:
Unable to log the data that I am asking the user to enter in the field of username and password.

Error:

There is no such error but the logs do not display the username or the password. Basically I am trying to add login functionality to the app.

SDK version is 28

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the `SharedPreferences` data in the onCreate method as soon as your `Activity` is opened, so it's writing the initial blank values of the `EditText`s into the `SharedPreferences`.

To fix it, you should write the data when you click the login button, rather than when the `Activity` is opened:

```kotlin
        loginbutton.setOnClickListener {
            username1.edit().putString("username", username.toString()).apply()
            password1.edit().putString("password", password.toString()).apply()
            Log.i("username is ",username1.getString("username","").toString())
            Log.i("username is ",password1.getString("password","").toString())
            val intent = Intent(this, ListActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

More broadly, there's no need to have separate `SharedPreferences` files for the username and password.  You could simply have one `loginInfo` preferences file and use that in place of both `username1` and `password1`:

```kotlin
val loginInfo = getSharedPreferences("loginInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
// replace instances of username1 and password1 with loginInfo
```